# How to increment using a SQL variable within an update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I am trying to increment a column using an `@count` variable in SQL. I have tried multiple attempts that I will list below that all result in:
`Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...`

First was:

```
SET @count = 65;
UPDATE table t
SET t.Revision = CHAR(@count)
, @count = @count + 1
WHERE t.hidden = 0;
```

I am trying to increment every row currently as a proof of concept that this works.

Second was:

```
DECLARE t CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE t.hidden = 0;

OPEN t;
FETCH NEXT FROM t;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table t2 SET t2.Revision = 'D' WHERE t2.id1 = t.id1 AND t2.id2 = t.id2;
    END;
END

CLOSE t;
DEALLOCATE t;
```

Once again I am just trying to see if I can set a standard variable using a while loop before I implement incrementing as a proof of concept that it works.

I am not sure why either of these attempts is failing but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ___for the right syntax to use near ...___ And the bit following that is the most important bit. So can you show us that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
SET @count = 64; -- so the first increment is 65 (starting on A).

UPDATE table_name t
  SET t.Revision = CHAR(@count:=@count+1)
WHERE t.hidden = 0;
```

or (shorter):

```
UPDATE table_name t, (SELECT @count:=64) t2
SET t.Revision = CHAR(@count:=@count+1)
WHERE t.Hidden = 0;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=072183da4cb2bcc7c2dd72c242cc2856)

Comment: Thanks, this one worked but my proof of concept. Also, I like how compact it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your first example should work(inside of some loop):

first you set your count value, then you update

```
SET @count = 65;
UPDATE CUSTOMER t
SET t.LName = CONVERT(@count, char)
where t.FName = 'a';
```

...and then increase that count and you update again...

```
set @count = @count + 1;
UPDATE CUSTOMER t
SET t.LName = CONVERT(@count, char)
where t.FName = 'a';
```

But that should be in a procedure for example.

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72e16b82472d320b69a089a6b46b51a0). I it a small example and I hope you will find it helpful.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this one also worked, but Sebastian's response was closer to my exact example so it worked better. Still, I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome. In my demo you have a procedure you can call and send her any number you want...so actual loop as you asked... Happy it helped. Cheers!